# Matlab process *always* sleeping

Tags: matlab, cpu-usage

At the university, no matter which server I use, running Matlab processes **always** appear to be in sleep state in `top` even though they are using 100% CPU (or 2400% CPU for multithreaded code). In weeks of monitoring I have found no exception.

Other programs with high CPU utilisation are in running state most of the time. Matlab never is.

Is there an explanation for why it is that way? I can't believe Matlab is polling the network or file I/O every single second. Do other people find the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because MATLAB runs many threads. The one you look at using `top` is the main thread, which is a sort of a manager for the others, and sleeps waiting for, e.g., user input. When inside `top`, type `H` to see all threads. You will see which MATLAB threads are doing the actual work.